# recommended way for app generated events to get onto users' Google calendars

Tags: django, google-calendar-api

I run a Django web app that schedules about 50 users for various events.  Users login to the site to view their schedule.  Of course, each user also wants their events on their personal Google calendar with real time updates.
For privacy reasons, it is important that the app not access the users' own calendars.

My question is:  What is the standard (recommended) workflow for a web app to accomplish this?
Based on my reading so far, here's what I' thinking:

1. Create a dedicated Google account for the app.
2. Within that account, create a Google calendar for each user.
3. Share the link to the calendar with each user so they can subscribe to it.
4. The app updates the calendars via the API.

Is this a good way to go or is there a better way?

Really appreciate any help.